# What do I need to import to fix "unresolved reference for @kotlin.Throws(IOException::class)"

Tags: kotlin

Every so often when I use Android Studio to convert from Java to Kotlin, some methods will have

```
@kotlin.Throws(IOException::class)
```

Then the `.Throws` will be highlighted on red and say that I it is an unresolved reference. I'm guessing I need to add to my gradle some sort of Kotlin extension but I don't know which?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
```

Comment: Oh really? I thought this was something new that maybe had some new behavior. Oh well. Thanks.